# Enchanted Book separation

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have found several Enchanted books with 2 enchantments for different items (eg Power III and Lure II)  Is there a way to separate them and combine others for the same item (eg sword or bow)?

Answer (score 3):

In the current version of Minecraft, there is no way to do this without using mods or creative mode.

If you would like a workaround to split books and have cheats turned on, you can split it using creative. Type `/gamemode 1` to switch to creative, then take each of the enchants on your book as separate items and destroy the original. Switch back to survival with `/gamemode 0` and act like nothing ever happened...

Note that this approach will not work if you aren't OP on a server or have singleplayer commands off.

Comment: @Grogbog60 If this helped you, please click the tick below the votes beside my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do this on pc or console edition nor pe but I do know that you can switch to creative and collect the enchantments separately. If it is he case that you have Lure II then if you do want the exact one you'll need to find it on a enchantment table or by a librarian in a village. Or you can cheat and get Lure III. Then switch back to survival and continue. I've had trouble with this myself. But don't worry. Just use all of our advice to help you.

Comment: I don't know if on pc you can just /give the enchantment book or not. I'm not a pro on pc but on console. You probably wouldn't care but still rather Tha going through creative. Just try using commands instead.